# Why <> operator fails and returns all the records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

For the last 1 hour I have been pulling out my hair on this query and it's result

```
select ac.* from [finance].[Accounts] ac
    inner join finance.AccountMapping ap
    on ap.Account_ID <> ac.AccountID
```

in accounts table we have an account ids 1,2,3,4,5,6
and in AccountMapping table we have an account_ID 1,2

but the above query still returns records for 1,2. Why? I have mentioned the return the records which doesn't match.

Comment: ac.AcountID = 3 or above then it will be different from 1,2

Comment: because `1 <> 3` etc...

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a `not in` filter.

Comment: ap.AccountID = 2 is not equal to ac.AccountID = 1

Comment: so for each record of AC is matched with all records of ap ?

Answer (score 2):

Because every record in `ac` presumably has at least one record in `ap` where the values do not match.  You probably intend:

```
select ac.*
from finance.Accounts ac left join
     finance.AccountMapping ap
      on ap.Account_ID = ac.AccountID
where ap.Account_ID is null;
```

Or, this might be a bit more direct:

```
select ac.*
from finance.Accounts ac
where not exists (select 1
                  from finance.AccountMapping ap
                  where ap.Account_ID = ac.AccountID
                 );
```

Comment: Gordon, switch it to LEFT JOIN. We know you wanted to perform LEFT ANTI JOIN ;p

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the result achievable with EXCEPT:

```
Select AccountID from AccountMapping
Except
Select AccountID from Accounts
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the way inner join's `ON` clause works: for each record of the first table it would find *all* records in the joined table that satisfy the condition. As long as you do an equijoin on a foreign-to-primary key, you get at most one record. As soon as you switch to `<>`, `>`, `<` etc. you could be getting multiple joined record for each record of the first table.

In your example you are looking for all rows where the ID is not matched. This is a perfect case for the existential quantifier, i.e. `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM [finance].[Accounts] ac
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM finance.AccountMapping ap
    WHERE ap.Account_ID = ac.AccountID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with left join and second table's Account_ID is null condition:

```
SELECT ac.* from [finance].[Accounts] ac
LEFT JOIN finance.AccountMapping ap
ON ap.Account_ID= ac.AccountID'
WHERE ap.Account_ID IS NULL
```

I hope this will help you.